# How to pass list to preparedQuery

Tags: quarkus, reactive

How to pass list of ids to query.

```
List<Long> ids;
...
client.preparedQuery("SELECT id, name FROM features WHERE id IN $1").execute(Tuple.of(ids))
```

When I passed this query an error occurred saying `invalid syntax near IN`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the `ANY` operator:

```
client.preparedQuery("SELECT id, name FROM fruits WHERE id = ANY($1)")
                .execute(Tuple.of(ids.toArray(new Long[ids.size()])));
```

With `IN` operator one has to specify each parameter, with the `ANY` you can pass an array.

Comment: I think that syntax not supported

Comment: Could you tell me the version of the library you are using?

Comment: Quarkus 1.13.3  [link](https://quarkus.io/guides/reactive-sql-clients#prepared-queries)

Comment: It's probably not possible. I've asked the question to the developers, I'll update the answer when they reply

Comment: I've found the right solution. This will work.